# Java Script Invalid Date

Tags: javascript

I am using jQuery datepicker for dates. Once dates are saved into the DB it shows on the screen; I would like to send the load time date to `new Date()`, but it shows "invalid format".

How can I fix it?

```
<input class="editTxtFrmt doj valid" `type="text" style="width:100%;">

var txt = name.replace("releavingDt","doj");
joinDt = $("input[name='"+txt+"']").val();      
new Date(joinDt)
```

Comment: So what format is it? What does `console.log(joinDt)` give you?

Comment: alert(new Date(joinDt));  Invalid Date

Comment: There are so many issues with the code you show us above.  Are you sure that is exactly what you are using? There is `backtick` right before your `type="text"`, there are no `<script>` tags for the JS, `joinDt` is referring to an `input` element with a `name` attribute (which your sample doesn't have), etc.  Please make sure you show us your EXACT code.

Comment: show us value of joinDt

Comment: 01 April 2013 jonDt value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is wrong with your code, but I will go line by line and point out some issues:

```
<input class="editTxtFrmt doj valid" `type="text" style="width:100%;">
```

There is a backtick right before `type="text"`.  Remove it!

```
var txt = name.replace("releavingDt","doj");
```

What is the value of `name`?  Where is it coming from?

```
joinDt = $("input[name='"+txt+"']").val();
```

You are looking for an input element that has a `name` attribute of whatever `txt` is.  Even if you get a valid string out of `txt` (which I doubt looking at the line above), your sample input element above, doesn't have any `name` attribute.  So `joinDt` will be `undefined`

```
new Date(joinDt)
```

This line is correct, ONLY if `joinDt` is valid.  However, given all the issues above, I strongly believe `joinDt` is `undefined` at this point.

How to debug:

Change the code to this and let us know what your alerts are giving you:

HTML:

```
<input class="editTxtFrmt doj valid" type="text" style="width:100%;">
```

JS:

```
alert("name is: "+name);
var txt = name.replace("releavingDt","doj");
alert("txt is: "+txt);
joinDt = $("input[name='"+txt+"']").val();      
alert("joinDt is: "+joinDt);
new Date(joinDt)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Steve I wrote jQuery for name it is working fine and the joinDt is 01 April 2011 it is coming from DB it is also fine

Comment: So have your run the coe I posted above? Can you please let us know EXACTLY what the alerts are outputting?  Not what the DB is giving you, but what the JS alerts are showing you.

Comment: alert gives Invalid Date and DB data 01 April 2013

Comment: I really don't want to be rude, but if you want our help, then please follow our instructions.  So I ask again: "Have you implemented the code I posted above?"  The one with the three alerts?  What are the EXACT alert outputs to ALL THREE alerts?

Comment: 1.name is: data[expsum][0][releavingDt]  2.txt is: data[expsum][0][doj] 3.01 April 2013  4.alert(new Date(joinDt)); gives Invalid Date

Comment: See, that doesn't make sense to me.  If your alert is "txt is: data[expsum][0][doj]", then your next line would be: `joinDt = $("input[name='data[expsum][0][doj]']").val();`, which is absolutely invalid.